# video records dont start from start with flex, webcam and red5

Tags: flash, apache-flex, webcam, red5

Video streaming to users work fine. All function works fine. But I have one problem.
When I start view file like: Video1.flv this video start not from start...
I use this code:

```
camera.setMode(640, 480, 25);
camera.setQuality(0, 85);                   
camera.setKeyFrameInterval(17);
ns.attachCamera(camera);
mic.rate = 44;
ns.attachAudio(mic);
ns.publish(video_name, record);
```

Comment: This might be the wrong code sample 'ns.publish' is for sending the stream to the server - not playing it back.

Comment: I get this file: http://www28.zippyshare.com/v/71618288/file.html
but its play from end..

Comment: I'd recommend you start with one of the numerous .FLV playback code examples and build up from there.